# Remove controller from url with typo3 and realurl

Tags: typo3, fluid, realurl

I'm building more complex url's and I would like to have them nice and with no unneeded info.

Therfore I don't want to have the typo3 controller in my url's. I fixed it for normal links by using the `<f:link.page>` instead of the `<f:link.action>` link.

Now I want to do the same for form's only fluid automatically ads the controller 
to the link. I tried the following form code but it also adds the current controller:

```
<f:form class="limitform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" pageUid="1" additionalParams="{extension: {page: '1'}}">
```

Is there a way the controller is not added?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the controller and/or the action in the RealURL config. Below follows an example, which removes both action and controller from a detail-link.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array (
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array (
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array (
                'yourDetailConfiguration' => array(
                        array(
                                'GETvar' => 'tx_yourext_pi[action]',
                                'valueMap' => array(
                                        'detail' => '',
                                ),
                                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                        ),
                        array(
                                'GETvar' => 'tx_yourext_pi[controller]',
                                'valueMap' => array(
                                        'Event' => '',
                                ),
                                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                        ),
                        array(
                                'GETvar' => 'tx_yourext_pi[event]',
                                'lookUpTable' => array(
                                        'table' => 'tx_yourext_domain_model_yourtable',
                                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                                        ),
                                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                                        'expireDays' => 180,
                                )
                        )
                ),
                '123' => 'yourDetailConfiguration',
        ),
);
```

Note, that you have to assign each **page UID** with your plugin (in this case page 123, which contains a detail page) to the desired configuration.

More information about this can be found in the extension [manual](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Administration/Realurl/Index.html) of the news extension. There you will also find alternatives to the solution above for removing controller/action.

Comment: It improves the url but still there is an extra field in the url. In my old setup my url was for example this: `/auto/contoller/Ads/car.html` and when I this this setup the coltroller is removed but the Ads is this there, like this: `/auto/Ads/car.html`. When I use the page links also the controller value is removed as the page default controller is used. Beside I have a multi domain setup so i don't want to use a page UID. But changing `'yourDetailConfiguration'` into `'_DEFAULT'` works also.

Comment: With the `'_DEFAULT'` the event "Ads" is also added on every page. Therefore making the other url's less clean. Is there no way that the form does not add the controller?

Comment: Good example, but also in typoscript you can add `plugin.tx_you_ext.features.skipDefaultArguments = 1`. This must clean from realurl default Controler and Action

Answer (score 0):

Best is to build speaking urls with the "fixedPostVars" (see other answer) and clean then long urls with the encode Hook from realurl:

```
// Replace
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['encodeSpURL_postProc'] = array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc');
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['decodeSpURL_preProc'] = array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'); //

function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('auto/contoller/Ads/', 'auto/Ads', $params['URL']);
}

function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('auto/Ads', 'auto/contoller/Ads/', $params['URL']);
}
```